# Drush memory exhaustion

Tags: drush

hi guys any of you experience having problems regarding memory exhaustion when running a drush command? I made a batch to add taxonomy and do a node_save after to all nodes (a lots of nodes) i've set the limit on settings.php to 1GB and still no luck, it always throws an error regarding memory exhaustion.

Comment: Can we have the exact error? Any additional details?

Comment: Please provide Drush and Drupal versions as well.

Comment: Sometimes CLI PHP has a separate ini file.  Worth double checking.

Comment: drush 4.5 & drupal pressflow 6.22

Comment: yeah that's what will i check now the cli php..

Comment: ok as i check and it respects the settings.php and it is set to 768M but still getting this


Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 325914 bytes) in /var/www/html/1680remapping.git.dev.cnngo.com/modules/memcache/dmemcache.inc on line 41
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                                                [error]

Answer (score 2):

Drush includes a sample php.ini file (there's an online copy [here](http://drush.ws/examples/example.drush.ini)) with instructions on how to override your the php.ini file that Apache uses.

Just copy the contents of the example file into one of the three locations listed in the sample file and save the new file as `php.ini`. I would recommend using either option except for your Drush installation as this will require you to re-create a php.ini every time you update Drush.

Running `drush status` shows you which PHP configuration file it is using in case you're unsure if your changes took effect.

Answer (score 1):

Drush is usually using different php.ini than your Apache, therefore you need to modify your configuration file separately.

To test what is the limit set for drush commands, you may run:

```
drush eval "var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));"
```

If you're not happy with your limit, then you may change it either in php.ini

```
$ drush status | grep php.ini
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/path_to_your/php.ini
```

by modifying the right line into (-1 for unlimited):

```
memory_limit = 1G      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (default: 8MB)
```

or by setting the limit in drushrc.php (e.g. sites/all/drush/drushrc.php) or in settings.php by adding the following line to the end of the file:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
```